# Does ARRAffinity cookie need HttpOnly flag

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, arr, cookie-httponly

I wanted to understand the security threat caused by not setting httponly flag for ARRAffinity cookie which is sent by ARR. Do i need to set the httponly flag? If not why?

Answer (score 0):

`ARRAffinity` cookie don't need `HttpOnly` flag. I found below feedback  which is raised in 2016. And Azure team gave response in 2017.

[Set ARRAffinity cookie with correct attributes - HTTPOnly & Secure](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/12437064-set-arraffinity-cookie-with-correct-attributes-h)

But now,`ARRAffinity` has set the `httponly` flag by default. We don't need to manually set `httponly`.

`ARRAffinity` and `ARRAffinitySameSite` are both used to tell Azure which `iis instance` should be reached.

Hope the following article can help you.

[Securing the ARRAffinity Cookie](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/securing-the-arraffinity-cookie/ba-p/342598)

If we set like below code, in our browser, we can't get cookies which is security.

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("AUTH_COOKIE"); 
myCookie.Values.Add("userid", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
myCookie.HttpOnly = true;
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12);
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

[image]

Comment: Does Azure sets the httponly flag as true by default now?

Comment: @AkhilReddyBandi Yes, I don't change anything on portal. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOUjA.png